# How to eliminate negative numbers while tracking an interval

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have developed a sheet that tracks a daily event interval. When the interval passes midnight I get a negative number. e.g. -23:00:00. Ultimately I want to average the interval, but including the negatives throws off the calculation. Any suggestions as to how to filter these out?

[image: Pond Interval Sheet]

Comment: As I recommended on your [last post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/164424), I suggest sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it). Formulas are written around data, and while we can *see* some data in your image, the volunteers here would need to open a new spreadsheet of their own and hand-enter your data before they could even begin to consider a solution, which will be a deterrent to many. Help us to help you: share a link to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Dan, I will add that it doesn't appear to me that you need Col B or Col C. The "Interval" can be derived directly from the Col-A data. And the entire column of "Interval" data can be returned with a single formula at the top of the column, rather than row-by-row formulas.

Comment: if you calculate the difference between the two timestamps you will not have negative elements

Comment: I will assume by the lack of communication from the OP that this is an abandoned post. Typically after 24 hours of no reply, I move on. Dan, if you ever do see this, keep in mind that this is a volunteer-run forum. As such, the volunteers should never be putting more effort into a post than the person who posted it. It's a small community here, and you'll hurt yourself with future posts if you become known as someone who does not reply when people put time into your posts.

Comment: Yes sorry, I contracted COVID and have been down. Thank you all for your advice. Please consider the issue resolved.